# Wordpress homepage ID

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I want to point a function that only works on the home, the problem is that I can´t find the ID of the homepage. How do I know which ID it has?

The id "home" doesn´t works...

Comment: What kind of function?  jQuery, PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your editor, when you edit your page, check the URL.  It will look something like this:

http://www.domain.co.uk/wp-admin/post.php?post=154&action=edit

Where your ?post={ID IS HERE}

In this example, my home page (or the current page I am editing) is 154.

Comment: Wordpress uses index.php as all it's pages, have you made a home page for your website using Wordpress?

Comment: No, just the inner page it´s made with wordpress, I used the index.php for the home

Comment: Yes, in Wordpress - under pages, by default Wordpress would have created a page for you.  You can select a page to be your home page under Settings > Reading > Font page displays > A static page (select below) > Choose your page/post

Comment: Again, Wordpress uses index.php as all it's pages, if you were going to put some static content on the page, you can create your own template file or you can edit page.php - Wordpress uses .htaccess to access the other pages by using PHP GET variables and changes them (depending on your permalink settings)

Answer (score 0):

No need to find the id of home page. Use the conditional tag [is home](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home)

```
<?php
if ( is_home() ) {
    // This is a homepage - write your function here.
} else {
    // This is not a homepage
}
?>
```

Comment: I believe the question states 'How do I know which ID it has?'.

Comment: "I want to point a function that only works on the home". This is what he is trying, right??

Comment: Yeah I'm sure he is, and I'm sure that's the exact function he needs - but this forum is known for being pedantic.

Comment: Actually, I tried to use ( is_home() ) but it wasn´t working before setting my index.php as a home template with this  "Settings > Reading > Font page displays > A static page (select below) > Choose your page/post"

Comment: That's where the is_home() gets it from.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create homepage template first, see here http://wsmithdesign.wordpress.com/2011/01/19/creating-a-custom-wordpress-home-page-template/
then you can create whatever function inside your homepage template.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this in function.php file :

1. If you are working on javascript based function:

   ```
           add_action('wp_head', 'functionForHomePage');
           function functionForHomePage(){

                if(is_home()){
                   //function body
                 }
           }
   ```

if above code doesn't work then try it:

```
<pre>
                    add_action('wp_head', 'functionForHomePage');
        function functionForHomePage(){  
             if(is_front_page()){
                //function body
              }
        }
</pre>
```

1. if you are working on php function:

   ```
           add_action('wp', 'functionForHomePage');
           function functionForHomePage(){  
                if(is_home()){
                   //function body
                 }
           }
   ```

if above code doesn't work then try it:

```
<pre>
    add_action('wp', 'functionForHomePage');
    function functionForHomePage(){  
             if(is_front_page()){
                //function body
              }
        }

</pre>
```

actually I don't know how do you setup your wordpress site, so here I post as par available information as you mentioned.

Hope this is helpful for you. All the best ;)